# I want to create a function call but function is not getting created

Tags: android, function

In Android development, I want to call a function called bindViews(), for that I am creating a function but instead, it's creating a method.please help me how Can I create a function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF31H.png)

Comment: This is Java code. You need to end the function call statement with a semicolon. Also, post the actual code, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: functions are the same thing as methods.